# Obtaining audio port in video calls with JnetPcap

Tags: java, sip, voip, jnetpcap

I'm trying to obtain the port of the **audio** media of SDP headers. I am currently using JnetPcap to catch traffic.

I am obtaining the Media value from the SDP headers like so:

```
sdp.getAVP(Sdp.Fields.Media.name());
```

(I know this is not the prettiest way, I have already asked for better alternatives [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172079/capturing-media-stream-port-of-sdp-header-using-jnetpcap).)

This does the job. Except for voice calls. When a call has video enabled the SDP header contains 2 Media values, audio and video. The problem is that the getAVP() method always only returns the video value.

How do I obtain the audio port?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve:

- Capture the traffic with Wireshark and look at the c lines and m lines manually
- Take the captured sdp object and do .ToString() and parse it yourself, line by line looking for m= and c=
- Take the sdp and parse it with [JAIN SDP](https://jsip.java.net/)

The structure of the SDP is defined by RFC 4566: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566 see chapter "5.14.  Media Descriptions ("m=")"

Comment: That's kinda pointing to what I did. I used sdp.text() to get the enter header, then using regex a stripped the audio port out.